# Bitbucket server - hide audit log

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

is there a way to hide the **Audit Log** menu item in a Bitbucket Server(5.13.0 - Data Center edition) from the project and repository settings?

Thanks,
Balázs

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't belive that there is. The menu however is only visible to Project / Repo Administrators. So, if you only have one admin, or less admins then that might be a solution.

You could also try and post your question over at the Atlassian community page:
https://community.atlassian.com/